# Solve the equation $x^n=a$ in a finite field

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Good evening! I'm studing something about finite fields and I didn't find anything that can answer my question.

I have a finite field $\mathbf{F}_q$ and the equation to solve is $x^n=a$. Which are the condition to resolve this equation? For which values of $q, n, a$ there exist a solution?

I will be very happy if anyone can answer this question, possibly with a reference of a book (or an article) that explai this with more details.

Thank in advance to everyone who can answer this one, I really need to understand this.

Comment: Well, $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ (or any other field) must contain an $\;n - $ th root of $\;a\;$ , and *also* the $\;n - $th roots of unity.

Comment: @Joanpemo No, $\mathbb F_q$ is not algebraically closed, in fact no finite field is.  There are plenty of values of $a$ that don't have square roots, and for some $n$ it might not contain non-trivial $n$th roots of unity.  Are you perhaps thinking of $\mathbb C_q$, the $q$-adic complex numbers?

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you, I know that. I was just addressing the asker's question: "what are the conditions to solve this equation?". Of course, you can always use an extension field.

Comment: @Joanpemo I'm afraid I don't quite follow how you can say that $\mathbb F_q$ must contain $n$th roots of $a$.  Passing to an extension field is not faithful to the meaning of "contains", is it?

Comment: @ErickWong For me "to solve the equation $\;x^n-a=0\;$" means to find all its roots or solutions (in $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ , as the asker wrote) . I just wrote what must $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ to fulfill for this to be possible... **in** $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ , of course. That's all.

Comment: @Joanpemo Erm, it sounds like you are describing "$x^n - a$ splits completely in $\mathbb F_q$".  This is not what the question is about (OP specifically asks when there is **a** solution, not when there are $n$ solutions).

Comment: @ErickWong Apparently you and I read different things in the question.  I read, even right now, that it is written "...the equation to solve", "...conditions to resolve this equation?" Then, after that, he mentions "...when...exists a solution".

Answer (score 2):

The case $a=0$ is easy to solve, let us look at $a \neq 0$.

The field $\mathbf{F}_q$ is cyclic. Let $b$ be a generator for the multiplicative group $\mathbf{F}_q^x$. Remember that the order of $b$ is $q-1$.

Your particular $a$ can be written as $b^k$ for some $k$. Writing $x=b^y$ the equation becomes
$$
ny \equiv k \pmod{q-1} \,.
$$

In particular, if $gcd(n, q-1)=1$ there is always unique solution. If $gcd(n, q-1)=d>1$, then there are solutions if and only if $d|k$, and this is equivalent to 
$$a^{\frac{q-1}{d}} =1$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unhappily, this will not help me, but as you know a lot about arithmetic in finite field, I will ask you something more specifically. I'm hoping that the equation $x^{q^r+1}=y^q+y$ has solutions for every $y\in F_{q^{2r}}$, Your answer will not help, because $gcd(q^r+1, q^{2r-1})=q^r+1$, unlucky. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: ah, r is odd!!!

Comment: @user149240 Isn't $gcd(q^r+1, q^{2r-1})=1$?

Comment: yes, I did a mistak, because the truth is that $gcd(q^r+1,q^{2r}-1)=q^r+1$, where $q^{2r}-1$ is the order of $F_{q^{2r}}^*$- Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user149240 The answer still helps, but now you need a way of evaluating $(y^q+y)^{q^r - 1}$.  If it's identically $1$ for all $y$ then it'll still work, otherwise there will be some counterexample.  Note that this is a polynomial of degree $q^{r+1}-q$, so it wouldn't seem like this will be constant over all of $F_{q^{2r}}$.  You should probably ask this as a separate question as this one is likely closable as a duplicate.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know much stuffs about this kind of calculation. If I could use my knowledge about algebric curves, this is very simple (this curve cover the Hermitian curve (for r=1) and that one is maximal, so it's true). But I pretend to explain this to some students in an elementary way, using elementary number theory can be very good for them, So I'm asking to people who can easily solve this problem, because if I had to do that alone, I will not have the oportunity to show them this problem, because I'll travel in another country in 2 days.

Comment: @user149240 Ah, for $r=1$ the degree considerations might just be okay (I forgot that $(y^q+y)^{q^r-1}$ doesn't need to be identically $1$: it could be $0$ or $1$).  But for $r>1$ I don't think this can be true for all $y$: this would mean that the polynomial $((y^q+y)^{q^r-1})-1)(y^q+y)$ is identically zero, but it only has degree $q^{r+1}$ whereas it would need to have degree $q^{2r}$ to be identically zero on $\mathbb F_{q^{2r}}$.